# Removing an HTML form from the DOM during JavaScript submit action

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Basically what it says on the tin. I have a form that generates a JavaScript action:

```
// in head
function process() {
    setupform = document.getElementById("setup");
    setupform.parentNode.removeChild(setupform);
    // do other stuff
}

// in body
<form id="setup" name="setup">
    <input id="entrybox" name="entry" type="text">
    <button type="submit" onclick="process()">Process</button>
</form>
```

When the form is triggered, the page reloads instead of continuing with the "other stuff" and leaves the form empty. No error appears in the error console.

I had another version of this where instead of removing the form from the DOM, it just had `setupform.innerHTML = "";` and it worked fine. However, leaving an empty element seems wrong. I'm just trying to figure out why the above code won't work.

I also do NOT want to use JQuery or any other frameworks, before anyone suggests that.

Comment: It is a submit button, so it submits the form when it is clicked. What did you expect? And what is *other stuff*?

Comment: Your button has submit function. If you don't want to send form data and redirect to itself (because you did nor set a form action), you have to set your button to `type="button"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to prevent the form from submission. That triggers the page refresh you are talking about.

```
<form id="setup" name="setup" onsubmit="return false;">
  <input id="entrybox" name="entry" type="text">
  <button type="submit" onclick="process()">Process</button>
</form>
```

The @boulder_02 comment is also right!

Answer (score 1):

The button is a `submit` button, so it will submit the form. And the default action of a form submit is doing a request to the URL specified by the `action` attribute.

If you don't want the redirection, you have two options:

1. Disable form submit completely. That way, *enter* presses in textboxes will trigger the function, but will not redirect to a new page.

   ```
   function process(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     setupform = document.getElementById("setup");
     // ...
   }

   document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', process, false);
   ```
2. Make the button a normal button by changing the `type` attribute to `button`. Users might still submit the form and thereby reload the page.